# QGIS "Categorized" Expression dialog , result show no "label/value" only "1"

Tags: qgis, symbology

In ArcMap when I use Categorized I can choose what values I want to display using the "Add Values" button. In layer panel the values I chosen will show up there with the correct name.

I tried the same in Qgis, but the values doesnt show, I only get a number 1 and 0 but not the actual name in the column of the attribute-table.

Here is how I do:
I got a layer with streets as polylines, each street has a streetname assigned to them in the attribute-table under the column "STREETNAME".

I go to "Properties->Style->Categorized".

Then I click the "Expression" button. In the "Expression Dialog" I create the following "expression".

"STREETNAME = 'ADAGE WY'
[image: Image showing the Expression dialog window]

Here comes the problem, after I clicked "OK" and then "Classify" to classify based on the expression I dont get any values in the value  column.
[image: Image showing the Layer Properties window and the values]

Is it supposed to work that way or am I doing something wrong? I was hoping that the streetname "ADAGE WY" would show as a "Value".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This result is correct, because you write expression `"STREETNAME" = 'ADAGE WY'` which gives you categories 1 (true) and 0 (false).

You can rename the legend value, or in *Column* left only `"STREETNAME"` and hit *Add* button and write value `ADAGE WY`

Comment: Is there any way to get the label automatically, to avoid users from writing in the wrong value/name?

Comment: Don't know if there is some simple solution. It would be nice to have option after hitting *Add* button choose value from list or similar feature.